# PHP $_POST not working

Tags: php, post

I'm following a PHP tutorial which is teaching about $_POST and it had me create an exercise with two pages. On the first page (Form page) it creates a form where a user enters Username and Password.  Once they click submit, it opens on the second page (process.php) where the Username and Password should be displayed as a result of using $_Post. However, when I click submit on the first page, it takes me to the second page where only the ":" in the Echo statement is displayed. No username, no password.

Any ideas? I've copied the form page and the process.php below.

```
Form page

<html>
<head>
<title>encode</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="process.php" method="post">
     Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
     <br/>
     Password: <input type="password" name="password" value=""/>
     <br/>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Process.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>encode</title>
</head>
<body>
 <?php
$username = $_Post['username'];
$password = $_Post['password'];

echo "{$username}: {$password}";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `$_POST` (all caps).

Functions are case insensitive, but variables aren't.

Comment: It is not about who is "first"!

Comment: @Tomalak It does to some degree. Should I answer a day old question with an existing answer reworded?

Comment: @alex: 15 seconds != 1 day. Plagiarism and "who beat you to the punch" are not the same thing!

Comment: @Tomalak Sometimes it can be difficult to differentiate the two.

Comment: @alex: I've never had a problem differentiating between a day and 15 seconds. But maybe that's just me!

Comment: @Tomalak I was referring to the latter *Plagiarism and "who beat you to the punch"*.

Comment: @alex: It was more fun to pretend that you were referring to the initial comparison.

Answer (score 1):

`$_Post['username']` doesn't work.  Must be `$_POST['username']`.  Same with the password field.  You need to enable error reporting in your php.ini configuration file.  It would have told you the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Variable names in PHP are case sensitive. You wrote `$_Post` where it should be `$_POST`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, PHP is case-sensitive when it comes to variable names, so change:

```
$username = $_Post['username'];
$password = $_Post['password'];
```

To:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```