# PHP Script Not Receiving Post Data

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

I have a php script that is processing a form for me.  However, something is strange (or I'm just a bigger noob than I think).

The following code at the top of the script:

```
<?php

// Get Post Data to Insert into Database

print('<pre>');
print_r($_POST);
print('</pre>');

$vehicleID = $_Post['list3'];
echo "Variable vehicleID is: {$vehicleID}";
echo "Post variable list3 is: {$_Post['list3']};

?>
```

Results in the following "printout" when the form is submitted and form data intercepted by the script:

```
Array
(
    [list1] => 7
    [list2] => 3923
    [list3] => 20745
    [Submit] => Submit
)
Variable vehicleID is: Post variable list3 is:
```

I've only included the post array printout to see if post data is actually being received - which, apparently, it is.  So, why is not passing into my variable so that I can USE it?

I know I'm just a PHP hack, but I feel like I must be losing it.

Comment: Use `$_ALLCAPS[...]` for any superglobal arrays (`REQUEST`, `POST`, `GET`, `SERVER`, etc).

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975404/php-post-not-working

Comment: Didn't you get an error for using a variable that doesn't exist? ($_Post) in the line `$vehicleID = $_Post['list3'];`

Comment: Don't try to tell me that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975404/php-post-not-working) was not you! (I realise the accounts aren't the same, but the name and the _exact_ error are...)

Answer (score 3):

Your code has `$_Post` and should be `$_POST`?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `$_Post` to `$_POST` in the lower part of your code; that may be what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The manual page on [the HTTP POST data superglobal array](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) describes it as `$_POST`.

And, [elsewhere](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> #### Basics
>
> Variables in PHP are represented by a dollar sign followed by the name of the variable. The variable name is case-sensitive.

Thus it follows that your use of `$_Post` should, in fact, read `$_POST`.

You should fix your `error_reporting` settings, because you should have seen an `E_NOTICE` about using a non-existent variable.

Comment: All of the answers I've received suggest the same modification to my code - obviously (and all of them solved my problem - boy do I feel like an idiot for not noticing it).  Anyway, this was the best answer so that others who do not realize variables are case sensitive will see that they are.  I DID know this, but for some reason wasn't thinking that POST needed to be all caps.